# Deriving closed-term formula from recurrence relation with linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, recurrence-relations

I've seen an example on Wikipedia on how to derive Binet's by using eigenvectors and eigenvalues ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)).
I tried to apply the same method to prove, for example, that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^9}\sum_{k=0}^nk^8=\frac{1}{9}$$ (I know there are a bunch of other better methods to prove this, but I just want to learn something new)

The sequence can be written in a recursive form, such as
$$
a_{n+1}=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^9a_n+\frac{1}{n}
$$

Then I defined the vectorial recurring sequence
$$
\vec{a_{n+1}}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^9&\frac{1}{n}\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues of the matrix are clearly $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^9$. The eigenvector relative to $\lambda_1$ is $\vec{\mu}_1=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{n^8}{\left(n-1\right)^9-n^9}\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Then, since $a_0=1$,

$$
\vec{a_0}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\vec\mu_1
$$

So

$$
\vec{a_n}=A^n\vec\mu_1=\lambda_1^n\vec\mu_1=\vec\mu_1
$$

Therefore $$a_n=\frac{n^8}{(n-1)^9-n^9}$$

The limit we get from this is clearly $\frac{1}{9}$ as expected, but the nth term of this final sequence doesn't match with that in the limit.
What's wrong with my proof?

Comment: Your matrix has entries which are a function of $n$, so it's changing as $n$ changes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks. There's no way to proceed like this then?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan also, why does the limit match? Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making $b_n = (n-1)^9a_n$ you can solve the recurrence as

$$
b_{n+1}=b_n + n^8
$$

with solution

$$
b_n = c_0+\frac{n^9}{9}-\frac{n^8}{2}+\frac{2 n^7}{3}-\frac{7 n^5}{15}+\frac{2 n^3}{9}-\frac{n}{30}
$$

and then

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)^9}\left(c_0+\frac{n^9}{9}-\frac{n^8}{2}+\frac{2 n^7}{3}-\frac{7 n^5}{15}+\frac{2 n^3}{9}-\frac{n}{30}\right)
$$

and clearly

$$
\lim_{n->\infty}a_n = \frac 19
$$

Comment: Ok, interesting. How do I get to that solution, though? If we try to use the eigenvalues method we still have a matrix depending on $n$, right?

Comment: To solve the $b_n$ recurrence is sufficient to assume $b_n = c_0+c_1 n+c_2 n^2+c_3 n^3+c_4 n^4+c_5 n^5+c_6 n^6+c_7 n^7+c_8 n^8+c_9 n^9$ and after that, determine  the $c_k$

Comment: Thanks. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

As Qiaochu Yuan pointed out in the comments, the matrix is itself changing as $n$ changes. Therefore multiplying by $A^n$ makes no sense at all.